# What to use : "that" or "who"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, ambiguity

Consider this sentence : 
"I was going down the hill and on my step down I saw a guy **who** appeared to be disguised".

"I was going down the hill and on my step down I saw a guy **that** appeared to be disguised".

which is correct usage of English in such case that or who?

Answer (score 1):

> I was going down the hill and on my step down I saw a guy ***who*** appeared to be disguised"

is the correct usage.

*Who* and sometimes *that* refer to people but only in informal cases. Hence avoid using *that* for people. *That* and *which* refer to groups or things.

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering questions that are likely candidates.